# How to change disable input placeholder every selected dropdown value

Tags: javascript, laravel

I'm making a form that have a group selected dropdown that consist of string stored from database (i did a @foreach loop through database via eloquent model to assign the dropdown value lists), on the below of the dropdown i have 3 disable inputs that are the column from database that have a correlation with the value of dropdown. I want that placeholder of disable input automatically change the value to be same as the record with the dropdown value's record from database once i select a value from dropdown. What should i do? What JS script should i use for?

[image: Form]

**blade.php**

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="selectError2">Plat Nomor</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <select data-placeholder="Pilih Nomor Polisi" id="selectError2" data-rel="chosen">
        <option value=""></option>
        @foreach ($park as $p)
          <option value="{{$p->id}}">{{$p->nopol}}</option>
         @endforeach
      </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="disabledInput">Jenis Kendaraan</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input class="input-large disabled" id="disabledInput" type="text" placeholder="{{$p->jenis}}" disabled="">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="disabledInput">Kategori Kendaraan</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input class="input-large disabled" id="disabledInput" type="text" placeholder="{{$p->kategori}}" disabled="">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="disabledInput">Waktu Masuk</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input class="input-large disabled" id="disabledInput" type="text" placeholder="{{$p->created_at}}" disabled="">
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huh finally i got the answer from one of my friend.

First, add attribute `id="your_id"` on every input that corresponds with dropdown's record.
After that, add this line of `<script>`

`

```
// Transform PHP variable into json, so it can be cached into js variable
// Adjust the param with @json($your_table_name)
const park = @json($park);

function change(select) {

// Get the id (which is in the value) of the selected option
let id = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value

// Find the data in the cached json
let parkData = park.find(function (p) {
  // Find it by id
  return p.id == id
})

// For each fields to be shown in the page...
// Each member of array are the same id from the <input> tag
// In this case i want three columns to be shown in the page..
for (let field of ["jenis", "kategori", "created_at"]) {
  // Put the data to the corresponding element
  document.getElementById(field).value = parkData[field]
}

}
```

`

Voila! It changed the value of disabled input each time i select the value of dropdown.
It does only need the Plain JS with no jQuery or any other JS framework. So simple :D

Answer (score 0):

You refer my sample code:

http://jsfiddle.net/18pa7m0q/11/

```
function change(select)
{
   var value=select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
   $(".input-large").attr("placeholder",value);
}
```

Comment: What should i do to make the value on the placeholder follows the value on the dropdown's record?

Comment: Have you browsed my link?

Comment: Not working, sir. I've put the script on the top of the blade file and add `onchange="change(this)"` on input tag but nothing change

Comment: do you know how to call jquery?
If you don't know how to call jquery, please browse the following URL:https://www.w3schools.com/JQuery/jquery_get_started.asp

Comment: I see. I have succeeded trying your script, but it only change the value of the id every time i select another value in dropdown. How could i change the disable inputs with the records that correlate with the dropdown value?

Comment: You may refer to my article: 
https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/18556/Using-a-drop-down-box-to-populate-a-second-drop-down-box.html